# Python Triple Quoted Strings in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio, ide, ironpython

I'm used to using Idle for Python development, but decided to give Visual Studio 2010 + IronPython a try last week.  It seems to work fine, but I noticed that triple-quoted (multi-line) strings don't highlight correctly in the editor.  See photo:

[image: The whole string block should be red]

Does anyone else have this problem or know of a good fix?  Apart from that bug, Visual Studio seems to be great for Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug that is already fixed for the next release - I screwed up storing our state while processing line-by-line when fixing another bug.

If you're really anxious you can actually build the MSI which includes the tools from the sources on CodePlex.  Once you have the VS SDK installed it should be as simple as running Scripts\Bat\Dev.bat to setup the enlistment environment and then msbuild Msi\Installer.proj which will produce an MSI in Bin\Debug.

Comment: Great!  Looking forward to the next release